# insert element above specific table row beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working with BeautifulSoup 4 and want to find a specific table row and insert a row element above it.

Take the html as a sample:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<span>Sample Text</span>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are many more tables in the document, but this is a typical structure. The tables do make use of names or ids and cannot be modified.

My goal is to locate **"Sample Text"**, find that `tr` in which it belongs and set focus to it so that I can dynamically insert a new table row directly above it.

I've tried something like in order to capture the top root table row:

```
for elm in index(text='Sample Text'):
     elm.parent.parent.parent.parent
```

Doesn't seem robust though. Any suggestions for a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. locate the text "Sample Text" using the [`text=`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) argument.
2. Find the previous `<tr>` using [`find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous).
3. Use [`insert_before()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) to add a new element to the `soup`.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<p>
<span>Sample Text</span>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find("span", text="Sample Text"):
    tag.find_previous("tr").insert_before("MY NEW TAG")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<table>
 MY NEW TAG
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p>
    <span>
     Sample Text
    </span>
   </p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice solution!!